# Incorrect result to input checking in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

**Message for MHS readers: Do not copy this code. Just use it for help with yours.**

I have 10 words loading from a file and then 9 are displayed in a grid. After 30 seconds 1 is removed and the 10th word from the file is put in. The user is then asked to guess these 2 words. They have 3 chances for each. When I enter the correct answer it still says I got it wrong. I even have it draw the correct answers to assist in testing. The result always comes back false.

These are the scripts:
ReadFile

```
global.DelWord = "Unknown";
randomize();                                                               
Fopen = file_text_open_read(working_directory + "\Words.txt");    
global.WordList = ds_list_create();
global.FileLen = file_text_eof(Fopen);
while(!file_text_eof(Fopen)){
    Fread = string_upper(file_text_readln(Fopen));
    ds_list_add(global.WordList,Fread);
    }
file_text_close(Fopen);
ds_list_shuffle(global.WordList);
global.WildCard = ds_list_find_value(global.WordList,global.FileLen);
ds_list_delete(global.WordList,global.FileLen);
```

DrawWords

```
z=0;
draw_set_colour(c_black);
draw_set_font(font0);
draw_set_valign(fa_left);
draw_set_halign(fa_bottom);
draw_text(100,100,"Code by kammak743);
draw_text(1600,900,string_lower(global.WildCard));
draw_text(1200,900,string_lower(global.DelWord));



for (x=0; x<3; x+=1){
    for (y=0; y<3; y+=1){
        draw_text((x*400)+700,(y*200)+290,ds_list_find_value(global.WordList,z));
        z=z+1
        }
    }
```

NewGrid

```
ds_list_shuffle(global.WordList);
global.DelWord = ds_list_find_value(global.WordList,global.FileLen);
ds_list_delete(global.WordList,global.FileLen);
ds_list_insert(global.WordList,global.FileLen,global.WildCard);
ds_list_shuffle(global.WordList);
```

CheckWords

```
Correct1 = 0;                                                        
OldWordA = false;                                                   
while (OldWordA == false) && (Correct1 <3){                      
    global.OldWordQ = get_string("What word was replaced?","");         
    if string_lower(global.OldWordQ) == string_lower(global.DelWord){  
        OldWordA= true;                                
        }
    Correct1 += 1;                                           
    }


Correct2 = 0;                                            
NewWordA = false;
globalvar NewWordA;
while (NewWordA == false) && (Correct2 <3){
    global.NewWordQ = get_string("What word is new?","");
    if string_lower(global.NewWordQ) == string_lower(global.WildCard){
        NewWordA= true;
        }
    Correct2 += 1;
    }


global.Win=false;
if (NewWordA == true) && (OldWordA == true){  
    global.Win=true;                            
    }
else{
    global.Win=false;                        
    }
```

DrawCheck

```
if global.Win == true{
    draw_text(900,900,"You won!!!");
    }
else{
    draw_text(900,900,"You failed");
    }
draw_text(400,50,global.OldWordQ);
draw_text(900,50,global.NewWordQ);
```

Comment: Share your project. Also I don't understand why you used `global.FileLen` because `= file_text_eof(Fopen);` - here always will be zero (`false`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `file_text_readln()` for read words from file, but this function also reads `CR/LF` codes ($0d, $0a), so when you compare two strings, like

`ABOUT` (ASCII codes: 97, 98, 111, 117, 116)

and

`ABOUT` (ASCII codes: 97, 98, 111, 117, 116, 13, 10)

it will return `false`.

Therefore you need change

```
Fread = string_upper(file_text_readln(Fopen));
```

to

```
Fread  = string_upper(file_text_read_string(Fopen));
file_text_readln(Fopen);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for explaining it well.

Comment: @kammak743 BTW, some things... 1). Not use `x` and `y` as simple variables, because it's internal properties (variables) of the objects. So, when you use `x` and `y` in `for` statement, you change state of current object. Use, for example,  `dx` and `dy` instead. 2). Not use `get_string`, use `get_string_async` (try press `Cancel` with `get_string`). 3). Statements like `if aaa == true { }` you can write as `if aaa { }` and like `if aaa == false { }` as `if !aaa { }`. 4). `a = a + 1` or `a += 1` -> `a++`. And many other... See example of some improvements http://pastebin.com/i3G6fMDY